# not solve the error ::protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable

Tags: go, ubuntu, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

protoc-gen-go-grpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go-grpc_out: protoc-gen-go-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.

not solve the problem for :
ubuntu so please give me the answers

`go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}`

and

`sudo apt install golang-goprotobuf-dev`

and

`sudo apt-get protobuf-compiler`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to:

```bash
go install github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go@latest
```

Then:

```bash
which protoc-gen-go
/${GOPATH}/bin/protoc-gen-go
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, execute the following:

```
go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

This will install `protoc-gen-go-grpc` executable to the location indicated by `$GOBIN` (default if not set is `$GOPATH/bin`)

```
$ ls $(go env GOPATH)/bin | grep 'protoc-gen-grpc-gateway'
protoc-gen-grpc-gateway
```

The protoc compiler is looking to run this executable, so you'll need to make sure it is resolvable via your `$PATH` environment variable.